# RxSwift call function for elements of array

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I have an array of devices, I want to try to connect to one of the devices, if it is successful stop trying to connect to other devices and return onCompleted, if the connection fails to the device, try next device in the array, and so on.

```
        Observable.from(devices)
        .enumerated()
        .flatMap { itemIndex, item -> Completable in
            return service.connectTo(device: item).catchError({ error in
                if itemIndex == devices.count - 1 {
                    return Completable.error(error)
                }
                return Completable.empty()
            })
        }
        .subscribe(onError: { error in
            // Do something with error
        }, onCompleted: {
            // Do something on completed
        }).disposed(by: bag)
```

I tried adding onCompleted just after connectTo(device: item), but this gets called after everything is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Right, because `flatMap` doesn't complete until every observable it's subscribed to completes. The trick is to have the connect emit a next event before completing and use `take(1)` in order to get it to stop.

For this use case, instead of using `flatMap`, I suggest you either use `merge` or `concat` depending on whether order is important, have the connections emit a next event before completing (with `andThen`,) and then follow up with a `take(1)`.

The `merge` operator will start the connection to every device. Once one of the devices succeeds, the `take(1)` will cancel the connection to all the other devices.

If you especially want to make the connect attempts one at a time, then `concat` would be a better choice. This will attempt each connection one at a time. Once one succeeds, the take(1) will stop the `concat` from trying any more.

```
protocol Service { func connectTo(device: Device) -> Completable }
struct Device: Equatable { let id: Int }
struct AllFail: Error { }

extension Service {
    func connections(devices: [Device]) -> [Observable<Device>] {
        devices.map { device in
            self.connectTo(device: device)
                .andThen(.just(device))
                .catch { _ in .empty() }
        }
    }
}

func mergeExample(service: Service, devices: [Device]) -> Observable<Device> {
    Observable.merge(service.connections(devices: devices))
        .ifEmpty(switchTo: .error(AllFail()))
        .take(1)
}

func concatExample(service: Service, devices: [Device]) -> Observable<Device> {
    Observable.concat(service.connections(devices: devices))
        .ifEmpty(switchTo: .error(AllFail()))
        .take(1)
}
```

The code above assumes that the `connectTo(device:)` method returns a Completable. Things are a bit simpler if it returns an `Observable<Void>`. In general, I recommend using `Observable<Void>` instead of `Completable`.

Comment: I tried both approaches, but the problem with merge is that it constantly connects to the latest device in the array. And the problem with concat is after an error happens it doesn't continue. And yeah connectTo is completable (using a public api). 
And also I have to use .cachError instead .catch (using an older RxSwift version), and I'm forced to use it.

Comment: If you are using an older Rx version that's fine, use `catchError`. I ran both code samples through a test harness. They work exactly as I described. The `merge` version will emit the first device that connects and cancel all the others. The `concat` version will attempt each device in turn until one connects, then stop trying. In both cases an `AllFail` error will emit if none of the devices connects. Make sure you are using my code exactly.

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit.

Comment: I'm using the same code. The concat version doesn't continue if an error happens (i tried multiple times). I have an array 3 devices, and the user is only able to connect to the last one, the first 2 should be skipped, I get a timeout error one the first but it connectTo is not called again

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Here is the test harness: https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/19966e573d5381422e454e6944d387c2 The last test is your example. (There are three devices, the first two fail.)

Comment: It could be an error in your `connectTo(device:)`. Are you sure the resulting Completable emits an Error on time out?

Comment: Hey man, it was on my end i was logging the wrong thing, your code is working perfectly fine. Thank you a lot.